# Split URL from position x to the end in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript I get a part of my URL via `location.pathname`.

Example: `/cakephp/public/home/Bob/documents`

I would like to split the result beginning from `/home` till the end so that my result looks like this: `/home/Bob/documents`. Important to note is that the end is not fixed. After `/documents` could come more.

With `location.pathname.split('/')[4]` I get `Bob`. But how can I get `/home/Bob/documents/...` via the split() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `'/home'` as the `split` argument, you can append the second element in the resulting array to the string `'/home'`:

```
'/home' + location.pathname.split('/home')[1]
```

---

**Edit:**

If there is more than one `'/home'` in the string, you'll need to handle that like this:

```
let splitPath = location.pathname.split('/home')

splitPath.splice(0,1)
```

and then you can get the processed path with:

`'/home' + splitPath.join('/home')`

Comment: There is no fixed end to my URL. Do you know how to make it dynamicly?

Comment: What do you mean by 'fixed end'? This will work regardless of how much is after `/home`

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you!

Comment: What if the URL looks like this: `/cakephp/public/home/Bob/documents/pictures/home/bathroom` and you end up with more elemnts in the array?

Comment: @GorkaHernandez Good spot - I've provided an edit that addresses this

Comment: @GorkaHernandez I don't know. I just tried the command from Jamie and it worked. I tried it with a longe URL and it gave me everything till the end. Or do I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @Magiranu my original answer wouldn't work with a location.pathname such as `/cakephp/public/home/Bob/documents/pictures/home/bathroom` - the edited response has a version that can handle that

Answer (score 1):

location.pathname.split('/'public')[1]

Answer (score 1):

This method takes care of cases in which the `/home` string appears more than once in the URL, such as:

```
/cakephp/public/home/Bob/documents/pictures/home/bathroom
```

But equally handles other paths.

```
function getUrl() {
    let splitUrl = location.pathname.split('/home'),
        result = '';

    for (let i = 1; i < splitUrl.length; i++) {
        result += '/home' + splitUrl[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```